# BJQS slider stop

Tags: jquery, slider

Anyone now what function can stop BJQS (Basic jQuery Slider) slider after e.g. click to a custom button?
And of course how to make it running again after clicking custom start button

Answer (score 0):

I also run into the same problem. However, I found the `settings.automatic = false;` option to prevent the slide from automatic sliding. I then declare a variable `stop : false` in the default variable and check in the `init function`:

```
var init = function() {
    if ( settings.stop ) {
       settings.automatic = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

So in my calling function, I simply called:

```
$('#banner-slide').bjqs({
    animtype      : 'slide',
    height        : 357,
    width         : 631,
    responsive    : false,
    randomstart   : false,
    stop      : true
});
```

Comment: if you have indeed got this to work then please can you revise your answer. there is no option called 'stop', so passing this to bjqs does not do anything, let alone stop the slideshow.

Comment: declared it in the default variable in the library and then check in the init function as my answer above

Comment: so I declared `stop: false` in the `defaults` variable and then included the `if` statement in the `init` function. I then set `stop: true` on an event, but when fired the slideshow keeps playing regardless..

Comment: I can confirm that this does indeed stop the slideshow, but only upon initial page load, which performs the same function as `automatic: false`, and does not relate to the question of firing on an event e.g. button click

Comment: yes, but so why don't we apply it to the click event of that button?

Comment: when I mentioned above "I then set `stop: true` on an event", this was applied to a click event. It seems that this only works on initial page load. whether this is to do with jQuery or BJQS I don't know. do you have any working examples or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
`funcion pauseSlide(){
    $('#date_ss').bjqs.pauseslider();
}
funcion resumeSlide(){
    $('#date_ss').bjqs.resumeslider();
}`
```

You have to try this. call function on button click. I hope it works.